# Path to an image in the local drive

Tags: java, html, image, path, tooltip

I'm using the following code to use an image in my local drive as a tooltip but it does'nt show the picture :

```
String path = "C:/images/A.png";
labelIMG.setToolTipText("<html><img src='"+path+"'></html>");
```

any work around for this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why on earth would a tool-tip be using an image on the local file-system of the end user?

Comment: I have a folder of images that contains a big amount of pictures, that I can't include it into my jar!

Comment: *"that I can't include it into my jar!"*  Of course you can.  That is just silly.  But if they are so 'big', how did you intend installing them to the client machine in the first place?

Comment: My idea is that I will make all packages (app+data) in a dvd so that the end user uses the data from this dvd.

Comment: So you are actually forming a file path/name to a ***file on a DVD?***  I can see that running into problems at time of deployment.

Comment: Maybe I'm going out of this thread border, but what kind of problems?

Comment: If by *"Maybe I'm going out of this thread border"* you mean 'should I ask a separate question?' then 'yes'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tooltip render is expecting a URL, not a file reference...

Try something like this instead.

```
String path = "C:/images/A.png";
File file = new File(path);
labelIMG.setToolTipText("<html><img src='"+file.toURI().toURL()+"'></html>");
```

You, could, of course, just use a simple `String`, but off the top of my head it might look something like `file:///c:/images/A.png` (I'm not a Windows box at the moment, so I can't check, sorry)

Comment: A local file will indeed need the prefix file://, just like an online one would need http(s):// or ftp:// ...

Comment: I'd recommend the first method, is it will you to run on different platforms